# Pointing A record to correct site on local domain

Tags: dns, xampp, windows-server-2003, a-records

i have a windows server 2003 running xampp on domain for support ticket system using ostickets for internal use only. I created an a record on domain controller pointing to the server 2003 machine so users would only have to go to support.companysite.com but when I go to that address i get the xampp homepage instead of the osticket site. I not very good with dns and windows server but I better with lamp stacks so I was wondering if anyone could help me point it to the correct site I would appreciate it. I cant move it to a dedicated lamp stack so it has to stay on the 2003 server.

Answer (score 0):

Is XAMPP installed on the same box as IIS or is it a different server?

If its the same server
I would suggest editing the binding for all the sites and/or use different port numbers.

For the default website (if it's not used) you can turn off the site, or give it a different binding, say www.companysite.com

Edit the binding of the support site to port 80 (or 81 if used by XAMPP), support.companysite.com.

If XAMPP is on a different server then perhaps you have your DNS A record pointed to the wrong IP Address.

Comment: IIS is installed with xampp but its not connected and default site is off. A record pointing to correct machine. Is it possible to create a virtual host in xampp? Would it work?